# Set Bookmarks Page to open in a New Tab in Opera Browser

Tags: browser, opera, bookmarks, tabs

How do I set `New Tab` to open the `Bookmarks` page by default instead of `Speed Dial` in Opera Desktop version?

I am using the latest Opera version 43.

I am able to change the startup behavior which is easy to change in the settings menu. But I want to specifically change the new tab behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an extension for Opera to set bookmark page in a new tab. There doesn't seem to be other ways to achieve that easily without using an extension.

- [Custom New Tab Page, by sanishmistry (deprecated)](/#) allows user to set a custom new tab page. This extension is no longer found at Opera add-ons website.
- [Homepage in New Tab, by shucream0808](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/homepage-in-new-tab/) enables user to set homepage and open in new or current tab. A simple extension that adds a "Home" button on toolbar.

Use either *one* of the listed extensions at above.

### Install extension

Latest version of Opera is preferred, although older versions may be able to install the extension.

1. **Use Opera web browser to visit Opera add-ons website** (link above). Check the extension name and its author name, to be sure.
2. In the right column of page, look for a green button **+ Add to Opera**.
3. Click the button once, then wait for the button to change from "Installing" to "✓ Installed".

If installation was successful, the extension will be listed by "Extensions" tab in Opera.

### Using extension

1. Go to **Menu > Extensions > Manage Extensions** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>).
2. In "Search extensions" field, type a keyword like "tab" to filter name of extension, or scroll and search manually. Then, click **Options** for the extension.
3. Enter the URL of your choice. For bookmark page, type either: `opera://bookmarks` (native) or `chrome://bookmarks` (since Opera 15).
4. Click **OK** to finish.

The end result depends on how the extension work (read the description for each at link above). Ideally, user will just open a new tab as usual. Otherwise, user may have to click on a toolbar button, or such to achieve the result.

### Bookmarks tab discrepancy

When "Bookmarks" tab is opened, "Unsorted bookmarks" is shown by default (Opera 42.0). Newer Opera will show "My bookmarks" (Opera 43.0) or "All bookmarks" (Opera 45.0). This behaviour seems to be non-customizable.

Tested using extensions for Opera, Custom New Tab Page 1.6.1 with Opera 42.0, 43.0, and 45.0; Homepage in New Tab 1.0.7 with Opera 45.0 and 57.0.

Comment: Thanks for the very well crafted answer. While this does answer the question I was hoping for a solution without any external plugins. It seems like an obvious feature to have natively.

Comment: You mentioned "There doesn't seem to be other ways to achieve that easily without using an extension." Could you point me to a not so easy solution? I don't mind getting my hands dirty with the browsers internals.:-)

Comment: @Harsh Opera had browser internals like Firefox, but that has changed; Even Firefox had its `browser.newtab.url` removed. So "without using an extension" would *not* mean looking into browser internals but the source code or less doable, which I don't know.

Comment: In that case this answer might currently be the only viable option. I wonder how the plugin developer has done it though.  MyTodo.add( Look at how plugins work.)

Comment: Also I have used `opera://bookmarks` as the local link which seems slightly more straightforward.

Comment: The add-on is now gone :(, any ideas how to get it back or are there any alternatives?

Comment: @icl7126 I have updated the answer. That is the only other extension for Opera that works. For native feature, look at Vivaldi web browser (also Chrome-based like Opera).